# How to do some action when routing?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I try to logout user when the token expires. I use jwt. I've tried to do it in app.component but it isn't effective until I refresh the page. Is there a way to systematically check it when routing? Data are stored in localStorage.

Comment: Just use router events .

Comment: Use a routing guard: https://angular.io/guide/router#milestone-5-route-guards

Answer (score 0):

You can do check with the help of route guards which will be called before activating a route. You need to configure this in routing module with the help of canActivate at each route configuration.
Implement canActivate in the guard to check if token is expired. If so you may want to redirect to login page.

Refer https://angular.io/guide/router#canactivate-requiring-authentication

Answer (score 0):

You can create an AuthGuard as below:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { CanActivate, Router, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from "@angular/router";
import "rxjs/add/operator/toPromise";
import { AuthService } from "./auth.service";
import { User } from "models/user.model";

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) {}

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    const isLoggedIn = this.authService.isLoggedIn;
    const currentUser: User = this.authService.currentUser;

    if (isLoggedIn == true && currentUser != null) {
      // check if route is restricted by role
      const roles = route.data.roles;
      if (roles) {
        const userRolesValid: boolean = this.authService.validateUserRoles(roles);
        if (userRolesValid == false) {
          // role not authorised so redirect to home page
          this.router.navigate(["/"]);
          return false;
        }
      }

      return true;
    }

    // not logged in so redirect to login page with the return url
    this.authService.logout();
    this.router.navigate(["/login"], { queryParams: { returnUrl: state.url } });
    return false;
  }
}
```

Then you have to add the AuthGuard as canActivate property to all the app routes you want this to be checked:

```
  { path: "home", component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]}
```

Please don't forget to also import the AuthGuard as a provider on the app.modules file

```
import { AuthGuard } from "services/auth.guard";

@NgModule({
    providers: [ AuthGuard ]

})
```